# How To write to Sub-D I/O using bash

Tags: bash, io

I want to control(write and read) the sub-d parallel Pins (usually used for interfacing a printer) using bash-scripts.
I know, that I could use pySerial or c, but I don't like them;).

I want to use the sub-d to controll external hardware,
and yes, I know, that I could use a RPi or something like that, but I want to use the parallel port of my PC

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try I/O on /dev/lp* or /dev/port (as mentioned [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/IO-Port-Programming#ss6.1) & [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/IO-Port-Programming#ss2.2)) using scripts though I have no idea if I/O redirection to those from bash scripts or using something like 'dd' will work as expected.
Use

```
~# echo -e '\x4' | dd of=/dev/port seek=1 oflag=seek_bytes
```

Comment: the sites you have linked are a little bit old, but the main problem is: I would have to write a kernel module, what I do not want to do. But thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: I don't see why you would need to write a kernel module assuming that the parallel port already appears as a `/dev/lp*` device. The second link describes using `/dev/port` using lseek/read/write etc. Assuming the info is sufficient to determine what to write and where on the device file to achieve what you intend, then you can use `dd` to write data on the device in shell script including skip etc -- see `man dd`. To feed binary input to `dd` you could use `echo` with escapes e.g. to write a byte 0x4 to port1 using `/dev/port` this could work: `echo -e '\x4' | dd of=/dev/port seek=1c`

Comment: Above example should be: `echo -e '\x4' | dd of=/dev/port seek=1 oflag=seek_bytes`

Comment: Ok, alright, was helpfull, I misunderstood your answer in compairson to the link, I'm sorry.